# vb.net - execute selenium ChromeDriver javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, selenium

I've seen numerous solutions for C# but I couldn't get it working in VB.NET. Maybe I am initalizing it wrong? I'd like to execute javascript over a loaded URL in the chromedriver.

My code so far:

```
Dim chromeOptions As New OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions()

chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.images", 2)

Dim driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()

driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True

driver = New ChromeDriver(driverService, chromeOptions)

Dim js As IJavaScriptExecutor = TryCast(driver, IJavaScriptExecutor)

driver.Navigate.GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/")

js.ExecuteScript("alert('hello world');")
```

It's not executing. Any help, please? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it.
Just add to the top of the code

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions
```

and use driver.ExecuteJavaScript("alert(0);")